# How do I use STIX Two integrals with another math font?

Tags: stix, integral, stix2

I tried to load this packages:

```
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage[notext, nomath, not1, notextcomp, upint]{stix2}
```

with the hope that **pdfLatex** on *Overleaf* (that I use) creates only STIX2's integrals and the the remain with STIX (NOT STIX2). But the result is that *Overleaf* doesn't make the STIX2's Integrals. WHY??

My code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage[notext, nomath, not1, notextcomp, upint]{stix2}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{STIX vs STIX2}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\Large

\section{Introduction}

\begin{equation}
\oint,\:\oiint,\:\oiiint,\:\intcup,\:\intcap,\:\sumint,\:\idotsint,\:\ointctrclockwise
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I'm using `book`-option. If there are no strongly solutions that immediately solv my problem, Could I load all STIX2's integrals that serve me, one at once? If so, how had I to do? Thank you so much

Comment: "Why does Overleaf not use STIX2's integrals?" I guess because you specified the `nomath` option.

Comment: Ok thank you, but now when I write greek letter, the output is STIX2's one. But I'd like the STIX's output one. How have I to do? Thx again

Comment: What's your reason for not wanting to use either XeLaTeX or LualLaTeX along with the `unicode-math` package?

Answer (score 5):

The `unicode-math` package provides a standard way to do this.  It requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  %StylisticSet=8, % Uncomment for upright integrals.
  range={"222B-"2233,"2A0B-"2A1C} ] % Integrals

\title{STIX vs STIX2}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\Large

\section{Introduction}

\begin{equation}
\oint,\:\oiint,\:\oiiint,\:\intcup,\:\intcap,\:\sumint,\:\idotsint,\:\ointctrclockwise
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: STIX Two Math sample]

There’s no way to do this with standard package options that’s compatible with PDFTeX.  So far as I know, you would need to load the math symbol alphabet containing the `stix2` integrals and redefine all their commands.

My advice is to use LuaLaTeX with Unicode when you can, and PDFTeX with legacy 8-bit fonts when you have to.

Answer (score 4):

Your setup essentially replaces most of `stix` actions with the corresponding ones of `stix2`.

You can replace the symbol like `stix2` does, using the right font.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stix}

\makeatletter
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwointegrals}{LS2}{stix2cal}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{stixtwointegrals}{bold}{LS2}{stix2cal}{b}{n}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallintsl}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"00}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smalliintsl}            {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"01}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smalliiintsl}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"02}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallointsl}            {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"03}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smalloiintsl}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"04}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smalloiiintsl}          {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"05}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallintclockwisesl}    {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"06}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallvarointclockwisesl}{\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"07}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallointctrclockwisesl}{\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"08}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallsumintsl}          {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"09}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smalliiiintsl}          {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"0A}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallintbarsl}          {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"0B}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallintBarsl}          {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"0C}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallfintsl}            {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"0D}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallcirfnintsl}        {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"0E}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallawintsl}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"0F}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallrppolintsl}        {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"10}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallscpolintsl}        {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"11}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallnpolintsl}         {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"12}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallpointintsl}        {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"13}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallsqintsl}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"14}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallintlarhksl}        {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"15}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallintxsl}            {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"16}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallintcapsl}          {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"17}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallintcupsl}          {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"18}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallupintsl}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"19}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smalllowintsl}          {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"1A}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallintup}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"1B}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smalliintup}            {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"1C}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smalliiintup}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"1D}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallointup}            {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"1E}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smalloiintup}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"1F}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smalloiiintup}          {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"20}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallintclockwiseup}    {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"21}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallvarointclockwiseup}{\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"22}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallointctrclockwiseup}{\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"23}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallsumintup}          {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"24}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smalliiiintup}          {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"25}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallintbarup}          {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"26}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallintBarup}          {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"27}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallfintup}            {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"28}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallcirfnintup}        {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"29}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallawintup}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"2A}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallrppolintup}        {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"2B}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallscpolintup}        {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"2C}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallnpolintup}         {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"2D}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallpointintup}        {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"2E}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallsqintup}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"2F}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallintlarhkup}        {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"30}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallintxup}            {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"31}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallintcapup}          {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"32}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallintcupup}          {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"33}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smallupintup}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"34}
\stix@MathSymbol{\smalllowintup}          {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"35}
\stix@MathSymbol{\intslop}                {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"94}
\stix@MathSymbol{\iintslop}               {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"95}
\stix@MathSymbol{\iiintslop}              {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"96}
\stix@MathSymbol{\ointslop}               {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"97}
\stix@MathSymbol{\oiintslop}              {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"98}
\stix@MathSymbol{\oiiintslop}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"99}
\stix@MathSymbol{\intclockwiseslop}       {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"9A}
\stix@MathSymbol{\varointclockwiseslop}   {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"9B}
\stix@MathSymbol{\ointctrclockwiseslop}   {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"9C}
\stix@MathSymbol{\sumintslop}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"9D}
\stix@MathSymbol{\iiiintslop}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"9E}
\stix@MathSymbol{\intbarslop}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"9F}
\stix@MathSymbol{\intBarslop}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"A0}
\stix@MathSymbol{\fintslop}               {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"A1}
\stix@MathSymbol{\cirfnintslop}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"A2}
\stix@MathSymbol{\awintslop}              {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"A3}
\stix@MathSymbol{\rppolintslop}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"A4}
\stix@MathSymbol{\scpolintslop}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"A5}
\stix@MathSymbol{\npolintslop}            {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"A6}
\stix@MathSymbol{\pointintslop}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"A7}
\stix@MathSymbol{\sqintslop}              {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"A8}
\stix@MathSymbol{\intlarhkslop}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"A9}
\stix@MathSymbol{\intxslop}               {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"AA}
\stix@MathSymbol{\intcapslop}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"AB}
\stix@MathSymbol{\intcupslop}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"AC}
\stix@MathSymbol{\upintslop}              {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"AD}
\stix@MathSymbol{\lowintslop}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"AE}
\stix@MathSymbol{\intupop}                {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"AF}
\stix@MathSymbol{\iintupop}               {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"B0}
\stix@MathSymbol{\iiintupop}              {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"B1}
\stix@MathSymbol{\ointupop}               {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"B2}
\stix@MathSymbol{\oiintupop}              {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"B3}
\stix@MathSymbol{\oiiintupop}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"B4}
\stix@MathSymbol{\intclockwiseupop}       {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"B5}
\stix@MathSymbol{\varointclockwiseupop}   {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"B6}
\stix@MathSymbol{\ointctrclockwiseupop}   {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"B7}
\stix@MathSymbol{\sumintupop}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"B8}
\stix@MathSymbol{\iiiintupop}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"B9}
\stix@MathSymbol{\intbarupop}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"BA}
\stix@MathSymbol{\intBarupop}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"BB}
\stix@MathSymbol{\fintupop}               {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"BC}
\stix@MathSymbol{\cirfnintupop}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"BD}
\stix@MathSymbol{\awintupop}              {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"BE}
\stix@MathSymbol{\rppolintupop}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"BF}
\stix@MathSymbol{\scpolintupop}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"C0}
\stix@MathSymbol{\npolintupop}            {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"C1}
\stix@MathSymbol{\pointintupop}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"C2}
\stix@MathSymbol{\sqintupop}              {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"C3}
\stix@MathSymbol{\intlarhkupop}           {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"C4}
\stix@MathSymbol{\intxupop}               {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"C5}
\stix@MathSymbol{\intcapupop}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"C6}
\stix@MathSymbol{\intcupupop}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"C7}
\stix@MathSymbol{\upintupop}              {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"C8}
\stix@MathSymbol{\lowintupop}             {\mathop}{stixtwointegrals}{"C9}
    \let\smallint=\smallintup
    \let\smalliint=\smalliintup
    \let\smalliiint=\smalliiintup
    \let\smalloint=\smallointup
    \let\smalloiint=\smalloiintup
    \let\smalloiiint=\smalloiiintup
    \let\smallintclockwise=\smallintclockwiseup
    \let\smallvarointclockwise=\smallvarointclockwiseup
    \let\smallointctrclockwise=\smallointctrclockwiseup
    \let\smallsumint=\smallsumintup
    \let\smalliiiint=\smalliiiintup
    \let\smallintbar=\smallintbarup
    \let\smallintBar=\smallintBarup
    \let\smallfint=\smallfintup
    \let\smallcirfnint=\smallcirfnintup
    \let\smallawint=\smallawintup
    \let\smallrppolint=\smallrppolintup
    \let\smallscpolint=\smallscpolintup
    \let\smallnpolint=\smallnpolintup
    \let\smallpointint=\smallpointintup
    \let\smallsqint=\smallsqintup
    \let\smallintlarhk=\smallintlarhkup
    \let\smallintx=\smallintxup
    \let\smallintcap=\smallintcapup
    \let\smallintcup=\smallintcupup
    \let\smallupint=\smallupintup
    \let\smalllowint=\smalllowintup
    \let\intop=\intupop
    \let\iintop=\iintupop
    \let\iiintop=\iiintupop
    \let\ointop=\ointupop
    \let\oiintop=\oiintupop
    \let\oiiintop=\oiiintupop
    \let\intclockwiseop=\intclockwiseupop
    \let\varointclockwiseop=\varointclockwiseupop
    \let\ointctrclockwiseop=\ointctrclockwiseupop
    \let\sumintop=\sumintupop
    \let\iiiintop=\iiiintupop
    \let\intbarop=\intbarupop
    \let\intBarop=\intBarupop
    \let\fintop=\fintupop
    \let\cirfnintop=\cirfnintupop
    \let\awintop=\awintupop
    \let\rppolintop=\rppolintupop
    \let\scpolintop=\scpolintupop
    \let\npolintop=\npolintupop
    \let\pointintop=\pointintupop
    \let\sqintop=\sqintupop
    \let\intlarhkop=\intlarhkupop
    \let\intxop=\intxupop
    \let\intcapop=\intcapupop
    \let\intcupop=\intcupupop
    \let\upintop=\upintupop
    \let\lowintop=\lowintupop
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{equation}
\oint,\:\oiint,\:\oiiint,\:\intcup,\:\intcap,\:\sumint,\:\idotsint,\:\ointctrclockwise
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Of course, you want to put all that code in a separate file.

[image]

I just took the block of integrals from `stix2.sty` and replaced `integrals` with `stixtwointegrals`, defining in the same way the symbol font, taking the code from the same file. The rest of the code is what's done in `stix2.sty` for the `upint` option.

Still, I can't understand why not using `stix2`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I answer to your question: I don't use STIX2 because I dislike its font, its greek letters, its Big-Operators, but very like its Integrals. Moreover, you told me **Of course, you want to put all that code in a separate file**, what do you mean, I don't well understand. Thx